# Select statement for getting the later date

Tags: sql-server, select

[image]

so heres my main table where in there are several dates on Eff_to

What is the select statement for getting the one with later date. By later means if a user inserts another date with later date the laptopid with the later date will be displayed.

Comment: and your attempt at the query is... where?

Comment: sorry i didnt post any "attempt query" because it has around 8 tables interconnected with this one and i just want to get the logic behind it so yeah no queries sorry ;)

Comment: The fact that your "real world" query is 8 tables has nothing to do with us. We don't know what you're working on. The fact that you simplified this down and STILL didn't attempt to solve your problem screams "I just want a quick solution". In fact, it's not even implied - it's quite explicit really "What is the select statement...". You will learn nothing from this, and you'll be on here again asking associated questions which you would know the answer to if you spent some time learning from making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean with 'latter date' is the highest date.
Try this:

```
SELECT LaptopID, Eff_to
FROM tbl
WHERE Eff_to = (SELECT MAX(Eff_to) FROM tbl);
```

Comment: thanks mr iswanto san youve been helping me quite a lot lately so yeah thanks ^_^

Comment: It's better to use '=' instead of 'IN' as MAX function will return single value only.

Comment: @alok_dida: yeah I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Provided the dates stored in your table are SQL Dates, you can use the [Max()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) function. This will return the latest date in the table.